# How do you use spell points as a Sorlock with the spell point variant rule?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, sorcerer, spell-slots, optional-rules

I am currently playing an Elf that is a level 5 Warlock / level 3 Sorcerer. My DM has graciously let me take a few short rests in the morning after my trance and before we start the adventuring day, letting me create extra level 2 spell slots (level 3  warlock spell slots get converted to 3 sorcery points, 3 sorcery spell get converted to level 2 spell slots). My group has tested the spell point variant rule, and want to use it.

### Question

How does converting warlock spell slots to sorcery points to sorcerer spell slots work with the *spell point variant rule* from the DMG?

Comment: The rule as written seems to only apply to classes with spell casting rather than pact magic. It seems like spell points give warlocks far more flexibility than what was intended for warlocks. So we aren’t currently planning on letting it apply to pact magic, but I don’t think the DM or myself are against the idea if there is a good reason for it.

Comment: Ok, so just the sorcerer (which makes sense) (I have seen some discussions of using spell points for warlocks ... but thanks for clearing that up)

Comment: Related on [Converting sorcery and spell points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148100/what-is-the-conversion-rate-for-sorcery-points-to-spell-points)

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that it works the same as it always did, but you can't create Spell Points from Spell Slots that you have. You can make Sorcery Points, but not Spell Points.

First, the spell point variant in the DMG says:

> With this variant system, a character who has the Spellcasting feature uses spell points instead of spell slots to fuel spells.

Since the rule only affects classes with the Spellcasting feature, Warlock's Pact Magic feature is not affected. This is reinforced when it later says:

> The Spell Points by Level table applies to bards, clerics, druids, sorcerers, and wizards. For a paladin or ranger, halve the character’s level in that class and then consult the table. For a fighter (Eldritch Knight) or rogue (Arcane Trickster), divide the character’s level in that class by three.

Note the distinct lack of Warlock being mentioned. Warlock is completely unchanged under the DMG's spell points variant rule

Additionally, even though you're using spell points to cast spells, the mechanic used actually uses spell points to create a spell slot which you then use to cast a spell:

> Instead of gaining a number of spell slots to cast your spells from the Spellcasting feature, you gain a pool of spell points instead. You expend a number of spell points to create a spell slot of a given level, and then use that slot to cast a spell.

So Spell Slots still exist and are still required to cast spells. Your character just uses Spell Points to create Spell Slots on-the-fly. It's also part of how they limit you from casting 6th through 9th level spells: you can only create one slot of those levels per day.

My reading, then, is that using Sorcery Points to Create Spell Slots actually functions identically. You don't (and can't) use Sorcery Points or Font of Magic to create Spell Points. You still use Sorcery Points just to create Spell Slots. You can turn those Spell Slots into Sorcery Points, but I don't see any way to turn Spell Slots back into Spell Points. You just don't get Spell Slots from your class anymore. Your class that has the Spellcaster feature gives you Spell Points. That's the only way to get Spell Points.

It's a very rough variant rule, however, so you and your table should expect to need to make a lot of rulings on use.

Comment: I agree that warlock's do not get access to spell points by RAW in the DMG.
It seems to strange to have spell points as a sorcerer and then convert your sorcery points into spell slots giving you three resources to manage (not including Pact Magic). Spell points are intended to make keeping track of your spell energy remaining easier. I hesitate to combiner sorcery points with spell points and not distinguish between the two as this makes sorcerers significantly more powerful as you have less transfer loss and are able to enhance your spells more easily from a larger pool.

Comment: @ObeseMonkey "Spell points are intended to make keeping track of your spell energy remaining easier." No they are not. The rule itself says, "Spell points give a caster more flexibility, at the cost of greater complexity." It's intended to be more flexible even though it's a lot more bookkeeping.

Comment: I missed that in the DMG, but I do not necessarily agree. A normal 17th+ level caster has to keep track of 9 different resources, his/her spell slots for each spell level. A caster using spell points only has to keep track of one resource. I view spell points as about as hard to manage as hitpoints as it is a single pool you need to subtract from as it gets used/taken. If I was to use spell points, would you recommend I keep spell points as one resource, generated Sorcerer spell slots as another, and sorcery spell points as a third or should I work with my DM to combine them in some way?